How to calculate the length of cycles in a graph using parallel algorithms in C?
I am getting desprite, because I can't solve this problem. I hope this is the right place to ask for help in this context.
The Problem is, that I have a graph that is the union of disjoint directed cycles. Additionally, there are  nodes (1), ..., () whose indices are stored in an array  of length  ≤ . The graph is represented by an array  of length , where () is the successor node of .
I need to calculate the length of the cycle containing each node in . The result should be an array  of length , such that (1), ..., () contains the length of the respective cycle.
Can anyone suggest an algorithm/pseudocode (in C) with a runtime of ( + log ) and work () to compute ?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated!
I could only create this Pseudocode:
for i in {1,...,k} par do

    while S[i] != i

        S[i] = S[ S[i] ]
        Y[i]++

with a runtime of (*log ) and work ()

Have you converted your pseudocode into C?  Did it work?  If not, have you researched graph algorithms to see if somebody has already solved this problem?

That pseudocode is not correct. The problem statement does not say the X(i) all refer to different cycles, and the pseudocode overwrites S, which can destroy information needed for another of the X(i). If the X(i) all refer to unique cycles, the work done by the pseudocode is O(n) because the total number of iterations of the inner loop is at most n, since the sum of the lengths of the cycles is n.

To get O(k + log n) time, you cannot partition the work into threads associated with each X(i), because there could be one cycle of very long length. You need to break up the work on each cycle.

Not familiar with parallel algorithms, but it seems you need to start with n parallel executions that merge chains. Initially you have n trivial chains of 1 vertex each, and at each step each chain either becomes a cycle or doubles in length.

"I need to calculate the length of the cycle containing each node in ."  There may be more than one cycle containing X.  Do you want the longest, shortest, or something else?

@ravenspoint: The cycles are disjoint from each other. The graph “is the union of disjoint directed cycles.”

Well then, this is trivial.  Split the graph into its components and count the vertices in each component that contains the Xs

@ravenspoint: How do you do that in O(k + log n) time?

In order to meet your time constraint, you need to start a process for each node, and those processes must be able to collectively process each node's cycle in O(log n) time.
By "processing a cycle", I specifically mean collecting the minimum or maximum of some function over all nodes in the cycle, and broadcasting it to all nodes in the cycle.  If you can do that, then your problem can be solved with this constant-length sequence of steps:

Find the node with the smallest index in every node's cycle.  This node will be the "representative" of each cycle;
Find the minimum number of steps from any node in each to the cycle representative.
Find the maximum of these minimums.  This will be the length of the cycle, which is the number of steps from the representative to itself.

Then you can just look up the cycle length for each of your k target nodes.
To process all the cycles in O(log n) time:

For each node i, let T[i] = S[i], let d = 1, and let V[i] be the target statistic for each node.  We will maintain invariants that:

T[i] = Sd[i]
V[i] = the min or max of the target statistic over d nodes starting at i.  For the "distance to representative" statistic, use n+1 if the representative is unreachable in d steps, and initialize V[i] = 1 for the predecessor of the representative.


Then we double d while maintaining the above invariants.  While d < n:

V[i] = minOrMax(V[i], V[T[i]]).  For distance to representative, use V'[i] = min(V[i],V[T[i]] + d).
T[i] = T[T[i]]
d *= 2



Note that each iteration of the loop in (2) needs to be done effectively synchronously for all nodes.  There are local O(1) ways to accomplish this.  Basically step d=2n cannot be processed for any node until its predecessors and successors in T are finished reading the results for d=n.
Once d>=n for all nodes, V[i] holds the same min or max value for all nodes in each cycle.

The predecessor of the representative is easily recognized by S[i] = representative
